# delta_time with the new move_and_collide() function in GameMaker

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker, deltatime

Is this implementation of delta time in recent Game Maker reliable?

```
var dt = delta_time / 1000000
move_and_collide(spd_h * dt, spd_v * dt,obj_world.solid_tiles);
```

It has the expected behaviour but I cant believe it can be that easy now.

Comment: What do you worry is inaccurate or unreliable about this?

Comment: I just cant tell, with my lack of experience in other engines or with other languages, if that will work as intended being a new function and all. In my old implementation of collisions I tried multiplying spd_h and spd_v by dt before adding to the respectives x and y positions and that did not work. In theory this should work the same but in that case it works.

Comment: Can you describe what did not work in that case?